# Beginner on Android - OnclickListeners

Tags: android

Just started learning Android coding. I know basics of Java and im improving on it. Learned about buttons and `OnclickListeners` so I thought of developing a simple program to use buttons and designed a calculator. Please help me if my logic is correct. When I press **Equals** (`beq` button) it doesn't work!

```
    int a, b, total,OP;
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b0, badd, bsub, bmul, bdiv, bclr, beq;
    EditText et;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
       b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
       b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
       b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
       b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);
       b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);
       b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);
       b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);
       b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
       b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);
       badd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
       bsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
       bmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
       bdiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
       bclr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clr);
       beq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eq);
       et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("1");
            } else {

                et.append("1");
            }
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("2");
            } else {

                et.append("2");
            }
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("3");
            } else {

                et.append("3");
            }
        }
    });
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("4");
            } else {

                et.append("4");
            }
        }
    });
    b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("5");
            } else {

                et.append("5");
            }
        }
    });
    b6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("6");
            } else {

                et.append("6");
            }
        }
    });
    b7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("7");
            } else {

                et.append("7");
            }
        }
    });
    b8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("8");
            } else {

                et.append("8");
            }
        }
    });
    b9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.equals("")) {

                et.setText("9");
            } else {

                et.append("9");
            }
        }
    });
    b0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           if (et.equals("")) {
               et.setText("0");
           }
            else {
               et.append("0");
           }
        }
    });
    badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText("");
            OP = 1;
        }
    });
    bsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText("");
            OP = 2;
        }
    });
    bdiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText("");
            OP = 3;
        }
    });
    bmul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText("");
            OP = 4;
        }
    });
    bclr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et.setText("");
            a=0;
            b=0;
            total=0;
            OP=0;
        }
    });
    beq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (OP){
                case 1:
                    b= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    total=a+b;
                    et.setText(String.format("%d",total));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    total=a-b;
                    et.setText(String.format("%d",total));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    total=a/b;
                    et.setText(String.format("%d",total));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    b= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    total=a*b;
                    et.setText(String.format("%d",total));
                    break;
              }
           }
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: In `onClick()` for `beq`, can you check value for `total`. Just do `System.out.println(total);`. The result will be in logcat under `System.out`

Comment: You could try one or more of the following; add a break point and debug; add a toast checking the value of OP a and b before the switch; add default to issue a toast. You could use Log calls in a similar way to toasts. My guess is that OP ends up not being 1,2,3 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

change 
  `int a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());`  in  `bsub,badd,bdiv,bmul`

to   `a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());`

Comment: The app works just fine. But when I do multiplication, the app does division. And when I do division, It does multiplication. Any suggestions?

Comment: change   `bmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
              bdiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);` to                                                `bdiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
              bmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);`